# Multiple AJAX calls optimisations

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET application which uses WCF services for AJAX requests. It is all working fine however seems to be taking quite a long time to load. Looking in the network tab in Chrome developer's tools shows why.

[image: Chrome developer's tools]

The first big request which is 560KB has quite a long TTFB which is expected due to generating all the data but the actual download time is basically instant. This great differs from the other AJAX calls though. I'm expecting a long TTFB for all of the requests however the others seem to be taking 4-5 seconds to download very small amount of data.

The web server is hosted in the same building as I am, doing a ping to the server I always get <1ms. So the physical connection to the server isn't the problem.

This leaves IIS, I've looked through the server config and couldn't find anything which would throttle multiple requests or anything like that, however I may have missed it. The ASP application may also be throttling requests however I couldn't find anything either. So the last thing is jQuery AJAX calls but I find that very hard to believe that would be causing it.

I would guess it has something to do with IIS but can't see what. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Aside from the issue, you really shouldn't be making that many simultaneous AJAX requests. Put all the required information in a single request and send that alone.

Comment: Try making the calls individually, just from hitting the Url in a browser (or use Postman or similar if they require headers or post data).  That will at least confirm whether or not it's the calls or the method you're using to make the calls that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Archer running them individually is very quick and loads pretty much instantly

Comment: That's good then.  You'll need to post the relevant code where you make the calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem it was caused by blocking javascript. I would say chrome listing the download time as a couple of seconds is actually incorrect as the file wasn't actually being downloaded during that time.